# Selenium web driver on AWS ec2: Unable to obtain browser driver and Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-webdriver, amazon-ec2

I am moving my project from a VPS to AWS EC2, it works on my old VPS ubuntu 22. But I encounter a error on AWS ec2 ubuntu 22.

env

- aws ec2
- ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
- node 18.17.1
- "selenium-webdriver": "^4.12.0",

error message

```
Error: Unable to obtain browser driver.
        For more information on how to install drivers see
        https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location/. Error: Error executing command for /home/ubuntu/myproj/source/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/bin/linux/selenium-manager with --browser,chrome,--output,json,--browser-path,/usr/bin/chromium-browser: /home/ubuntu/myproj/source/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/bin/linux/selenium-manager: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

    at getPath (/home/ubuntu/myproj/source/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/common/driverFinder.js:38:11)
    at thenableWebDriverProxy.createSession (/home/ubuntu/myproj/source/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chromium.js:692:43)
    at thenableWebDriverProxy.createSession (/home/ubuntu/myproj/source/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:224:13)
    at createDriver (/home/ubuntu/myproj/source/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:152:33)
    at Builder.build (/home/ubuntu/myproj/source/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:680:16)
    at /home/ubuntu/myproj/source/dist/utilities/selenium.util.js:72:37
    at step (/home/ubuntu/myproj/source/dist/utilities/selenium.util.js:33:23)
    at Object.next (/home/ubuntu/myproj/source/dist/utilities/selenium.util.js:14:53)
    at fulfilled (/home/ubuntu/myproj/source/dist/utilities/selenium.util.js:5:58)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

What I tried

- https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location/. It is not working.
- Also I tried to run my project on my PC WSL2 ubuntu 22, it works.

My observation

- After watching the selenium source code, it stop at `node_modules/selenium-webdriver/common/seleniumManager.js`
- `driverLocation()` and the function inside `spawnSync(smBinary, args)` throw error `Syntax error: "(" unexpected`.
- It looks like it is the problem of bin `/home/ubuntu/myproj/source/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/bin/linux/selenium-manager`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is chrome do not support arm64 until now and my ec2 instance is using arm architecture. To run selenium, it should use chromium and chromedriver.

Install the following packages works again

```
sudo apt-get install chromium-browser chromium-chromedriver
```

```
sudo snap install chromium
```

```
chromedriver --version
```

Comment: /usr/bin/chromedriver is a binary not a directory. Thus no point to add it with the export. /usr/bin by default should be in the PATH. Especially when you add it via apt. So it will be delivered to the known path already.

Comment: sure just updated